# Vuejs work on old browsers if using vue via cdn?

Tags: vue.js, cross-browser

i wonder that Vue.js will work on old browsers if i import vue to my html via cdn?

like:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

doubtful. If the website is not working when you building it with Webpack or load the vue code from your own server, then loading from a CDN will now not make any difference.  It is the exact same code. 
your best bet is to use Webpack, and polyfill the code to work with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this reading for all your questions.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist